# Get integer difference between string just like strcmp

Tags: java, string-comparison

I just need a function that will, for two given strings, return negative, positive or zero value. In C, `strcmp` is used:

```
char* a = "Hello";
char* b = "Aargh";

strcmp(a, b);  //-1
strcmp(a, a);  //0
strcmp(b, a);  //1
```

Does Java have any easy intuitive way to do it, or do I have to use the `Comparator` interface?

Comment: I really wonder what's wrong with this question and why was it downvoted. I see no comments or close votes...

Comment: me too - have an upvote

Comment: Well You have an option to create your own method but after saying this all the Users will want to Slap me and they will kindly suggest me not to create method while Java has this kind of method.But Java Has `a.compareTo(b)` so for your satisfaction you can create `strcmp(a,b)` for Specially C Lovers!! :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Does Java have any easy intuitive way to do it?

Yes, it does: `java.lang.String` implements `Comparable<String>` interface, with `compareTo` function:

```
int comparisonResult = a.compareTo(b);
```

There is also a case-insensitive version:

```
int comparisonResult = a.compareToIgnoreCase(b);
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning case insensitive option! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The [String.compareTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29) method is the way to go in Java.

How to use it :

```
import java.lang.*;

public class StringDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str1 = "tutorials", str2 = "point";

    // comparing str1 and str2
    int retval = str1.compareTo(str2);

    // prints the return value of the comparison
    if (retval < 0) {
       System.out.println("str1 is less than str2");
    }

    else if (retval == 0) {
       System.out.println("str1 is equal to str2");
    }

    else {
       System.out.println("str1 is greater than str2");
    }
  }
}
```

Output :

```
str1 is less than str2
```

Example taken from : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/string_compareto.htm

Answer (score 1):

What about [`compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29)?

```
int value = a.compareTo(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [compareTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29) but should include a null check as well if you want to be safe:

```
if (a != null){
    result = a.compareTo(b);
} else {
    //decide what to do here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is previously answered, Java has a built-in `String.compareTo(String anotherString)` method, you should checkout the **runtime** sources (you should search google for **rt.jar**).

However, here is a working sample with same logic applied on the `compareTo` method;

#### Method Implementation

```
public static int stringCompare(String str1, String str2) {
    char[] charArray1 = str1.toCharArray();
    char[] charArray2 = str2.toCharArray();

    int lim = Math.min(charArray1.length, charArray2.length);

    int k = 0;
    while (k < lim) {
        if (charArray1[k] != charArray2[k]) {
            return charArray1[k] - charArray2[k];
        }
        k++;
    }
    return charArray1.length - charArray2.length;
}
```

#### Demo Code

```
public class StringCmp1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1 = "aa";
        String str2 = "ad";

        System.out.println("Comparison of '" + str1 + "' and '" + str2 + "'");
        System.out.println("Custom Method    : " + str1.compareTo(str2));
        System.out.println("Built-in Method  : " + stringCompare(str2, str1));

        System.out.println("\nComparison of '" + str2 + "' and '" + str1 + "'");
        System.out.println("Custom Method    : " + str2.compareTo(str1));
        System.out.println("Built-in Method  : " + stringCompare(str1, str2));
    }

    public static int stringCompare(String str1, String str2) {
        char[] charArray1 = str1.toCharArray();
        char[] charArray2 = str2.toCharArray();

        int lim = Math.min(charArray1.length, charArray2.length);

        int k = 0;
        while (k < lim) {
            if (charArray1[k] != charArray2[k]) {
                return charArray1[k] - charArray2[k];
            }
            k++;
        }
        return charArray1.length - charArray2.length;
    }

}
```

#### Output

```
Comparison of 'aa' and 'ad'
Custom Method    : -3
Built-in Method  : 3

Comparison of 'ad' and 'aa'
Custom Method    : 3
Built-in Method  : -3
```